# Are questions asking for off-site resources on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question ([Are there any gltf example datasets available?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/416/are-there-any-gltf-example-datasets-available)) asks about some downloadable models in a specific format. Do we consider questions asking for off-site resources on-topic?

Other sites commonly have a close vote reason like

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software, tutorial **or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Startups as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe your problem or need and the steps, if any, you've taken to solve it.

(Stolen from Startups SE. But also similar on Stack Overflow)

Note: Software Recommendations are already [in discussion](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/are-questions-about-software-recomendation-in-scope).

Comment: Resource questions are a double edged sword. The good ones are really good (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list ), but the bad ones are really bad. Perhaps make it allowed only until you see it becomes a problem.

Comment: @Rotem There *may* actually be some recommendation questions that are good. However, the question you linked, in my opinion, is an example of a very **bad** question on SO as it violates many of the asking rules described in the Help Center (e.g. it is extremely broad and subjective). Yes, it is highly up voted, but it does not fit into the Q&A style, as it is more like a discussion than a question that can be answered objectively.

Comment: Of course, it is a terrible fit for the guidelines, as any such ridiculously nonspecific question would be. I didn't mean to say it is a good *question*, just that I found it a valuable resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that such questions should be off-topic. Keep in mind that if you open the site to some resource requests, you open them to all.

So while in the very beginning with a limited audience you may see good questions getting asked for resources you know have been - and will be - around for ages, you're ultimately setting yourself up for any range of crap on both the question and answer side of the equation.

So I'd start out by simply not allowing it. Clear and simple.

If anything, if there are some de-facto resources someone should know about, perhaps integrate them into the tag-wiki. Yes, I know, not very visible. But who knows, we may one day solve that problem.

Comment: Same applies to recommendation questions.